# Closed with respect to norm in normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis

In general, it is true that finite dimensional normed vector subspaces are closed. Does this mean they are closed with respect to any norm?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is in some sense not well-posed: to be closed for a vector subspace $U$ of a normed space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ is a topological property, where one considers the topology on $V$ induced by the norm on $V$. However if $U$ has finite dimension, then all norms on $U$ induce the same topology. Since the restriction $\|\cdot\||_U$ is a norm the answer to your question in some sense is Yes.

Comment: Why is it true that all norms on $U$ induce the same topology?  And how can we show that $U$ is closed? For $u_k \in U, u \in V$, if a sequence $||u_k-u|| \rightarrow 0$, then why is $u \in U$?

Comment: In a finite dimensional, normed space convergence of a sequence is equivalent to the convergence of the coordinate sequences with respect to a basis -- this is a result proved in Functional Analysis. Consequently convergence with respect to any norm only depends on convergence in the scalar field, which yields the statement about the norms. The same basic property yields that a finite dimensional, normed space is complete. Thus a finite, dimensional subspace of a norme space is closed.